# Disable a <p> using JQuery

Tags: jquery, paragraph

```
<p style="" class="closeField float_left" disabled="true"> 
  <a href="/knome2/comments/115/report_abuse" class="btn lbOn"><span class="button_image">
  <span class="report_abuse background_16">Close</span></span></a>
</p>
```

I am trying to make this `<p>` appear disabled. Actually this `<p>` tag will display like a button by CSS...

How do I make this `<p>` tag appear disabled in JQuery?

Comment: What do you mean by disabled?

Comment: Could you move your question out of the code block?

Answer (score 6):

Best way to create an element that looks like a disabled button is to create a disabled button. Do you know that `<button>` tag allows inserting complex html inside it?

Answer (score 2):

if you use this P for a click event, and you mean "disable" to stop the event.

then you can unbind the event
    $("p").unbind("click")

or if you mean to lower the opacity as if it is disabled you can set the opacity via 
    $("p").css("opacity",0.7), 
or you can animate the opacity via 
animate 
    $("p").fadeTo("slow", 0.7);

This this solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a disabled style in CSS and then apply it with jQuery

Answer (score -1):

you can use `$('p').remove()` or `$('p').empty()` if by disabled you mean disappear.